# How is Bootstrap / Moment DateTimePicker failing to display the correct 24 hour format?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I've been plugging away at this for too long and I cannot see where the formatting for Bootstrap's datetimepicker control is being overridden.

The Bootstrap DTP uses Moment.js behind the scenes to format its time picker. The JS code looks like this:

```
selector.find(".datepicker").each(function() {
    var $that = $(this);

    $that.datetimepicker({
        sideBySide: true,
        useCurrent: false,
        minDate: new Date(1910, 1, 1)
    });

    $that.children("input").on("focus", function() {
        $that.data("DateTimePicker").show();
    });
});
```

Nothing appears too complex there and the formatting in the HTML looks similarly simple:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.DateTime, new { @dateFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm", @mandatory = true })
```

However when the model is bound to the view and the JS iterates over the inputs, the times displayed go from 24 hour (e.g. `14:00`) to 12 hour (i.e. `02:00`).

I'm convinced this has to do with moment.js integration and very likely its handling of timezones but I can't see where I might apply different settings. Suggestions would be more than welcome at this point.

[image: HTML output]

Comment: Which is the datetimepicker you are using? I think that you are using [eonasdan datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/), in this case it's better to retag your question. Moreover I think that explicitly set [`format`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#format) option to `DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm` will fix your issue. By default the component uses `DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A`

Comment: Yes, that's the one I'm using. Sorry for not being specific.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your issue, it works for me using `data-date-format` as shown in the image, can you provide a fiddle or a snippet? Maybe is someting related to MVC and not limited to JS, HTML and moment.

Comment: It's _possibly_ related to MVC, but I can see the data coming down the wire with the correct values and it's bound to the view with the correct values. It's only when Moment / Bootstrap get their hands on it that the times are reverted back to AM. 
I'm 90% confident something in my JS is the problem. Possibly timezones.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $that.datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm',
        sideBySide: true,
        useCurrent: false,
        minDate: new Date(1910, 1, 1)
    });
```